# What is http request "HTTP/0.0"?

Tags: http, web, httprequest, client-server, httpresponse

I make some Angular calls to an API and sometimes I see the request is being requested with protocol 0.0 - "HTTP/0.0" (ideally this would be "HTTP/1.1") by client and in response we see nothing but "HTTP/0.0 0"

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no!

Answer (score 0):

In our case it turned out that Chrome was recording a blank HTTP version in its network log for requests that failed. The 'response' had a blank HTTP version too. Fiddler shows blank HTTP versions as HTTP/0.0.

You don't say where you saw your HTTP/0.0, but if it was in fiddler then even in the 'raw' view it's actually manipulating what you see.

You can double check this by downloading the .har file (right click in the network tab of the dev tools) and viewing the .har in a text editor rather than in Fiddler or some other viewer that might manipulate the results.